# Unable to merge dex this error keeps getting everytime

Tags: android

The error is Error

```
   :Execution failed for task 
   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I have tried all the solutions given on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.

This is app level gradle file. I think I am using all the latest dependencies.
app level build.gradle file is uploaded here. help me to solve this problem

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
     android {
              compileSdkVersion 26
              defaultConfig {
                applicationId"com.example.pratikrathi.registerapp"
          minSdkVersion 20
             targetSdkVersion 26
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
             multiDexEnabled = true
             testInstrumentationRunner 
       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

       }
        buildTypes {
          release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
               'proguard-rules.pro'
              }
            }
           }

        dependencies {
           implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
           implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
           implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.0.2'
           implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
           implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
           implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
           testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
           androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
           androidTestImplementation 
           'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
            compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
            compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
            annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
         }
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please attach your `build.gradle`

Comment: this is link for the build.gradle file "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H9r-900xOQ1JhBld3LBMsPoZXGHRMFuG"

Comment: It happens when external libraries cause conflict in android studio.
Did you try adding: multiDexEnabled true ==> under debug in gradle.build?

Comment: yaa I have tried that one also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing old firebase dependencies with the new firebase dependencies.

You need to remove the following from your root build.gradle dependencies:

```
    classpath 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

Then check and remove old firebase depedencies from your module build.gradle. Please read https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/google-android

---

**UPDATE**

You also have a duplicated support library.

`'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'` library implicitly using support library version 27+, which you can check from its [root build.gradle](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/build.gradle).

You can fix it by exclude support library from image-cropper like this:

```
  implementation ("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
  }
```

Or updating all of your support library to version **27.1.0**.

Comment: what should I write instead classpath 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

Comment: you need to remove it. To use the firebase, add the dependencies to your app module build.gradle not to project build.gradle. Use something like `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-***:11.8.0"`

Comment: When I tried to add "multiDexEnabled = true" then it is showing me error like this "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Pratik Rathi\AndroidStudioProjects\RegisterApp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Pratik Rathi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\830aa746032ec117427cfcfc7933682b\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))"

Comment: @PratikRathi: that is means you're having a duplicate support library. Please attach your app module build.gradle in your question.

Comment: checkout I have uploaded app level gradle file